# Flex: Use Text File as Input Stream

Tags: c, lex, flex-lexer

So I've used flex to generate a c file from my lex code, and then used gcc to create the corresponding actual parser .exe. However, I can't figure out how to get it to read from anything other than my own typed input. I am trying to get it to parse a huge dictionary file. Can anyone help?

Comment: `program < huge-dictionary-file` will do the trick in the short term; that's input redirection.  You have to set the input function so that it reads from your chosen file instead of standard input (which is a reasonable choice for the default source).  I'm going to need to check on the mechanism for that...the mechanisms in Flex and Lex are different.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two ways of solving it. The first is to redirect input from standard input with the command prompt `<` operation:

```
> parser.exe < some_file.txt
```

The other solution is to let the program open the file, and tell the lexer what the file is. For more information about it see [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html). The important functions are `yy_create_buffer` and `yy_switch_to_buffer`.

Comment: There are a number of other relevant sections, such as the one about EOF handling and yywrap.  The YY_INPUT macro is part of the answer.  Nevertheless, the manual pointed to treated as a whole covers the issue.

Comment: In my instance, Im integrating flex code into my executable and all I had to do was add a line yyin = fopen(myFile, "r") and flex read from the file with no need to use yy_create_buffer or yy_switch_to_buffer. Im assuming the previous two functions are only needed if flex is *not* integrated into a user executable? Im trying to ensure Im not being naive in assuming just because in my case "it works", that its necessarily "right".

Answer (score 13):

Try to add the following code to your *.l file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Adding onto the above answer by @Eliko, while using flex with yacc/bison, you can define `FILE *yyin;` in the global part of your grammar.y file. The definition in the generated lex.yy.c is an `extern FILE *yyin` by default. Thus, in your `grammar.y`, do something like this:

```
/* Some other global definitions */
FILE *yyin;
%%
/* Grammar rules*/
/* Grammar rules*/
%%
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
  /* Process command line args*/
  yyin = fopen("input.c", "r");
  yyparse();
  fclose(yyin);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to use `extern File *yyin` just above the `main` function.

Answer (score -1):

In **UBUNTU**
Position terminal in folder where is **.l** file then type following:

```
flex nameOfFile.l
```

then

```
gcc lex.yy.c
```

then `./a.out <nameOfFileYouWantToPass.extension` (eg. `./a.out <test.txt`)

**.l** file and **test.txt** should be in same folder